# Overload variadic template's fixed parameters

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Is it possible to override a variadic template by changing the number of fixed parameters before the function parameter pack?  For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...Args>
void foo(std::string, std::string, std::string, Args...) 
{ 
  std::cout << "THREE STRINGS\n"; 
}

template <typename ...Args>
void foo(std::string, std::string, Args...) 
{ 
  std::cout << "TWO STRINGS\n"; 
}

int main() {
  foo("key", "msg", "data", 1);
}
```

Running this causes the second `foo` to be called, but I want the first to be called.  Is there a better way to overload this function?

Answer (score 6):

Second variant is selected because it does not involve an extra conversion required to create an instance of `std::string` for the last argument. If you call class constructors explicitly (or adjust arguments to take exactly what you pass) then it will work fine:

```
foo(std::string{"key"}, std::string{"msg"}, std::string{"data"}, 1, 2); // THREE STRINGS
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4XG3Y6pDyNhAWShL)

Comment: He can also use operator literals to make it less verbose: `foo("key"s, "msg"s, "data"s, 1, 2);`

Comment: @0x499602D2 You are right, however `operator""s` was introduced only in C++14, while question is tagged C++11. Also there should be `using namespace std::string_literals;` to make `s` work so using it (at least for a single call) won't really improve things much.

Comment: Sorry, its tagged incorrectly.  We are using C++14, so the operator literals would work also.

Comment: Yep, sorry.  Done.

Answer (score 4):

This is because a string literal is not of type `std::string`. It is of type `const char[N]`. So the type of the third parameter of the function instantiated from the second function template is deduced to be `const char*`, which is considered a better match than the function instantiated from the first function template.

You can change the type of the parameters from `std::string` to `const char*`, or use explicit conversions suggested by VTT's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by VTT and xskxzr, `"data"` is a string literal, so is a `const char [5]`, so is convertible to but not exactly a `std::string`, so a generic template type is a better match than a `std::string` and the compiler prefer the first version.

You can choose the first version of `foo()` passing a `std::string{"data"}` but, if you don't want to change the call, another possible solution is SFINAE enable/disable the second version of `foo()`.

I mean... if you write a `fIsCToS` (as "first is convertible to string") custom type traits as follows

```
template <typename...> // for empty `Args...` list case
struct fIsCToS : std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct fIsCToS<T0, Ts...> : std::is_convertible<T0, std::string>
 { };
```

you can rewrite the second version of `foo()` using it as follows

```
template <typename ...Args>
typename std::enable_if<false == fIsCToS<Args...>{}>::type
   foo(std::string, std::string, Args...) 
 { std::cout << "TWO STRINGS\n"; }
```

The following is your modified example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename...>
struct fIsCToS : std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct fIsCToS<T0, Ts...> : std::is_convertible<T0, std::string>
 { };

template <typename ...Args>
void foo(std::string, std::string, std::string, Args...) 
 { std::cout << "THREE STRINGS\n"; }

template <typename ...Args>
typename std::enable_if<false == fIsCToS<Args...>{}>::type
   foo(std::string, std::string, Args...) 
 { std::cout << "TWO STRINGS\n"; }

int main ()
 {
   foo("key", "msg", "data", 1, 2); // now print THREE STRINGS
 }
```

If you can use C++14, you can use `std::enable_if_t` instead of `typename std::enable_it<...>::type` so the second `foo()` can be simplified as

```
template <typename ...Args>
std::enable_if_t<false == fIsCToS<Args...>{}>
   foo(std::string, std::string, Args...) 
 { std::cout << "TWO STRINGS\n"; }
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, so I came up with a different solution.  I hate answering my own question, but this is sort of the answer I was looking for and maybe it can help others.

What I did instead was to not overload the templated function and instead combine the entire signature into a single parameter pack.  Then, I overloaded a non-templated function that does the actual work, using `std::forward` to forward the args to one of these overloaded functions.  In this way, I let the compiler decide which method to call.

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_call(std::string key, std::string msg, std::string data, int)
{
  std::cout << "THREE STRINGS\n"; 
}

void print_call(std::string key, std::string msg, int)
{
  std::cout << "TWO STRINGS\n"; 
}

template <typename ...Args>
void foo(Args &&...args) 
{ 
  print_call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
  foo("key", "msg", 1);

  foo("key", "msg", "data", 1);
}
```

See it running [here](https://repl.it/repls/DeafeningGrotesqueDatalogs):

Comment: Well, this cannot solve the general case asked in your question: already your own `foo("key", "msg", "data", 1, 2);` fails.

Comment: I see what you mean.  The ints in the first example were just examples of extra args.  it was really about overloading the strings.  i can adjust my original question if it makes it clearer

Comment: You didn't get it. Your post was about a function taking an *arbitrarily* variable amount of arguments. Your 'solution' only allows two different versions. Moreover, there is no need for your template: just rename the `print_call` to `foo` and ordinary function overloading will do the same.

Comment: My original question was not about a function taking an arbitrarily variable amount of arguments.  It was about overloading the fixed parameters of a signature that contained a function parameter pack.  So, while the pack allowed for arbitrary amounts of arguments, I wanted to allow for the overloading of the _fixed_ variables.  My original question showed an example allowing two or more strings only.  So while it may have been a bit more flexible, it still would've required additional overloads to grow in flexibility.  I can update my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Your 'solution' does not allow the (general) parameter pack asked in the post.